# Executable optimization

Tags: assembly, compression

Is there some way that will absolutely optimize assembler? Like it will have drop every remembering of data used only once. Which will create from actual big 3d files amazing 4kb demos like [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1YZufDSD3IE)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, even an optimizing compiler cannot replace the genius of these demo programmers who are real experts not only in computer graphics but also in programming CPU's squeezing every possible bit of performance out of them.

---

Note: Assembler files are not 3d files. They do not contain a movie or the like. They contain an algorithm written in machine code that generates (synthesizes) the movie on the fly as you are looking at it. Therefore these demos cannot be compressed with compression algorithms like zip, gzip or mpeg. The effect of optimizing compilers is very limited. An optimizer attaining a reduction of code size of 30% would be a very good one. But you cannot expect it to reduce a code of say 80KB in size to 4KB.

Comment: Let's be clear -- demos like this often _are_ compressed with compression algorithms. It is just that the decompression algorithm also has to be part of the 4KB.

Comment: OK, maybe embedded bitmaps and meshes are compressed, but the code itself cannot be compressed very well. Try to zip an exe, you will be disappointed.

Comment: The code too. A DEFLATE-type compression can (1) replace duplicate code segments with back pointers (12 bits suffice) and (2) do bit reduction on the the most commonly used data/opcodes. Zipping a random EXE will be a poor test as the arbitrary binary has plenty of bloat (example: turning EXCEL.EXE into a self-extracting zip EXE reduces the size by 1/2) and ZIP is not optimized for this purpose. [Note: These roughly correspond to (1) factoring and (2) code threading, so if you are already making heavy use of those the savings might be less.]

Comment: You are right. I think the important point here is to understand that no video is stored that could be compressed. See [General real-time competition rules](http://www.assembly.org/summer12/demoscene/realtime) (one page down): "Entry must in an executable form. Pure animation files are not allowed in realtime competitions. Also executables only including an animation and an animation player will not be accepted."

Comment: And you are right too. The most impressive demos will rely an order of magnitude more on coder skill than compression. If you wanted to render a tree for example, you'd probably do so algorithmically with fractals. Using the algorithm would save you the most space compared to say a polygon model. Subsequent compressing of the code would save you relatively little. The space constraints are so tight compared to the desired effect that often both techniques are required.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure exactly what you are asking, but when space is the constraint, you can squeeze in more by using [Threaded code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threaded_code), including Huffman coding, and a high degree of [factoring](http://www.ultratechnology.com/Forth-factors.htm) (both hallmarks of traditional Forth programming). The rest is up to the skill of the programmer.